# How to vectorize creating a new column with values based on other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vectorization

Concerning the following dataframe, how do I create a new column "ADDRESS" of which the cell value for each row is a concatenation of STREET and NR using **vectorization?**

```
STREET     | NR
Astreet    | 10
Bstreet    | 20
...
```

I am aware that this can be done by iterating on the rows of the datraframe (non-comprehensive loop for clarity):

```
address_list = []

for index, row in org.iterrows():
    line = '{0} {1}' .format(row['STREET'], row['NR'])
    address_list.append(line.strip())

df['ADDRESS'] = address_list
```

This does the job but is not very time-efficient since it is an iterative operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join columns togeheter with space between and then use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['ADDRESS'] = (df['STREET'] + ' ' + df['NR']).str.strip()
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['ADDRESS'] = df['STREET'].str.cat(df['NR'], sep=' ').str.strip()
```